# Printing ?? instead of number in String.format("%02d",10) in java

Tags: java, string, format, string.format

I am writing code for formating using String.format. so in genral it should print number only but instead of printing number it is printing ??. here is code.

Any suggestion please what i'm doing wrong here. Thanks in advance.

**code**

```
int num=10;
String str='a'+String.format("%02d", num);
System.out.println(str);
```

**output:**

```
a??
```

Comment: Running your code the output is „a10“. Also when running the alternative `System.out.printf("a%02d%n", num);`. Must be related to your terminal or the code shown is not the one producing that output.

Comment: How are you running this code (IDE / console)? As @Christoper mentioned above, the code works fine - this most likely is related to your terminal settings.

Comment: @vini, I'm running this code on Eclipse 2022-09 (4.25.0) version, and I haven't changed default setting of IDE.

Comment: Which is your default locale? May it use digits that your console cannot display correctly? Could this explain he question marks? `String.format()` does use localized digits, for example `١٠` for Arabic.

Comment: test `format(Locale.ROOT, "%02d", num)` or set the default Locale: `Locale.setDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT, ...`

Comment: Thanks @user16320675, it run successfully using Locale.ROOT.